# GitHub .gitignore recommendation

Tags: git, github, gitignore

which folders/files should be excluded in `.gitignore` file?

I'm creating a project consists of:

1. /node_modules  => contains dependencies
2. /dist          => contains the compiled .js & .d.ts files
3. /src           => contains .ts files (the main project)
4. /test          => contains .js & .ts just for testing

I usually exludes the `/node_modules` & `/test` but not sure to exclude the `/src`.
Any idea?

Comment: What you exclude depends on what you have included before.

Comment: Do you mean by "exclude" that it should be *ignored* or that it should be *not ignored*?

Comment: Presumably all you need to know is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61982834/what-should-contain-gitignore-file-when-is-a-public-repository).

Comment: Why would you exclude `/src`; that's the one thing you _do_ want to version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore any file that is generated. If I download your project, I can use package.json to generate node_modules, so ignore node_modules.

But if I download your project and it doesn't have src will I still be able to generate src? Most likely not, as this is probably code you have written so put it up.

Comment: Yeah you're right. My assumption is includes the minimum working package, so i thought it should the generated & minified version of work. If the user need the source, just visit the linked github.

Comment: all files in `dist` are generated. should I exclude it?

Comment: if all files in `dist` are generated then yeah exclude it (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: How about the `dist` should be ignored in repo but doesn't in npm. And for `src` should be ignored in npm but not in repo. Because in repo to share the source code but in npm share the final minified version.

Comment: Perfect! (That is too short to comment but its fine with this useless addition)